# How to show number_field after clicking radio_button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm new to rails and i would like tohave number_field to show out after the user clicked the radio_button. For example, i have 3 radio_buttons. If the user clicked the 2nd one, it'll then show a number field to ask the user to enter some data required and later on pass to a function defined in controller after user click submit button.

Comment: I'd probably use jQuery to handle events on clicks of the radio buttons. The event would then append the number field on the click of the radio button.

Comment: does rails suppoert jQuery ? O.O

Comment: yes if it's not defaulted in your gemfile, you can always add in gem 'jquery-rails' and bundle

Comment: Erm i searched more information about using Jquery, and i have a few questions...
1) if i'm getting inputs from a FORM (in the VIEW ), how should i use jQuery ? MORE IMPORTANTLY where should i write this JQuery code in ? [ SOrry new to Rails]

Comment: I'm currently using VIEWS to pass the data values user give me [including the selection of radio_button value ] . If i were to use the Jquery, should i shift all the codes into somewhere ? WHere should i write my Jquery code in ? Sorry new to rails ...